# Connecting to SQL Server on AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-rds

I have an SQL Server running on an AWS RDS Instance. I can connect fine using SQL SMgr on my local machine but I get an error message from an application I run on my local machine which needs to publish data to the DB. I've read some stuff about VPCs and security groups but wanted to know if this is actually possible.

The error message reads:

> COM Error
>   Code = 80004005
>   Code meaning = unspecified error
>   Source = Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
>   Description = Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Jord, I had a similar issue.  It worked fine local, but failed when I moved the db to AWS.  I found that my connection string had "Integrated Security=True" set.  Once I changed it to false, everything lit up fine.

Also, another name for it is "Trusted Security", so that should be 'False" too.

Here is what Microsoft says:

> **Integrated Security -or- Trusted_Connection**
>   'false' When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
>   Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28VS.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396